# Considering putting unfinished or finished storage in second floor over living room with a raised ceiling

Tags: finishing, attic-conversion

A large area of my living room has a 10ft ceiling, which is raised 1ft from the surrounding 9ft ceiling. Currently there is nothing on the second floor over that raised ceiling, and there is no access to it, but there is a bedroom with a wall that essentially aligns with the raised edge where I could place a door / entry way. See picture below. Red area is the open space above the living room, blue is where a door would likely be

If I were to want access to the area above the living room, what's the best way to handle that transition? (In terms of safety and appearance). I may initially use it as unfinished storage space, but I'd want to eventually finish it completely. And maybe in the *distant* future just take out the wall and extend the bedroom into that space? Not sure, but first I just need access to it.

Should I have a single ~1ft step up? Or two steps, one of which would have to stick out into the bedroom? Obviously If left unfinished I would have to put an exterior door there, but would still be curious as to how to handle the step up.

[image]

Comment: pictures would really help.   especially a couple of the attic.

Comment: A bit funny that there is such a large area without access in a house.

Comment: @crip659 A couple reasons for this #1. The area is partially underneath a gable so there wouldn't be a full 9ft ceiling available over some of it, and on top of that add the -1ft head space because of the floor, and #2. The house is custom construction, and it wasn't in our budget to finish unnecessary areas at the builders price. I'm capable of this type of finish work myself, aside from the raised ceiling wrinkle.

Comment: @DMoore There is no attic. This is a 1.5 story home. The roof is pitched high so there is lots of 2nd floor space, but essentially no attic above it. And that unfinished area has no access. I will eventually have to cut out drywall and studs to put eyes on the actual area, but I'm getting as many recommendations as possible prior to that.

Comment: Think putting a door in that wall should be okay.  The other wall might be load bearing, so more needed for it.  The raised ceiling needs to be checked for how much load it can handle.  Is it raised for the whole room(wall to wall), or just a section in the middle?

Comment: @crip659 The living area is an open layout so the *normal* ceiling joists have to span ~18ft. However only a ~12x12 area is raised. I remember confirming with the builder that the area over it could be used for storage in the future, but I will still have to remove drywall to know for certain what load it can handle.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* your question is:

> Can I have a 12 inch step into this storage area or must I have a step in bedroom #4 for access?

The maximum riser height is somewhere around 8" to 8-3/4", and the maximum *difference* between riser heights is 3/8". So you would need to put one step into the bedroom and they would each need to be a 6" rise.

The step doesn't *have* to be into bedroom #4, but if it isn't, it's going to require an intrusion into the raised ceiling structure, so this would, by far, be the easier option. Building a little box, setting it on the floor and screwing it to the wall so it doesn't move is *very* easy in comparison to cutting into the floor/ceiling joists in this "bonus" area to recess the step. That is, of course, an option depending on your tastes and budget, but how to do so would be a whole new question and require a *lot* of details on the joists in question.

Comment: To guess that wall would be structural and load bearing.   With the size of the room below it I cannot see how it wouldn't be.   Also having bought houses with these unique layouts on heights... everything tends to be load bearing.

Comment: @DMoore I assume that means that knocking out the wall would not be simple.  I believe adding an entry way should still be straight forward though. Is there a way to specifically tell if a wall is considered load bearing?

Comment: @TheShoeShiner there are quite a number of questions about it here, but they all really boil down to "get a structural engineer on site to look at _your_ house". Frankly, he's the guy who will sign off on design plans to make a change like this using his education and state issued license to stake his name and career on being right about it. The best you'll get from here is a bunch of very well intentioned and well meaning guesses.

Comment: @TheShoeShiner - not really.   Load bearing on 2nd floor is actually easier if there isn't much above it.   You will obviously need a beam to support span issues but a lot of time this is easier on 2nd floors and 15 Foot I beams are pretty cheap if you can hide them.